# Поиск по данным и вывод результата indexOf()

Tags: javascript, json

Добрый день, у меня есть данные в таком формате:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Alexandra Palace",
    "code": "AAP",
    "lat": 51.59793,
    "lon": -0.12023
  },
  {
    "name": "Achanalt",
    "code": "AAT",
    "lat": 57.60958,
    "lon": -4.91386
  },
  {
    "name": "Aberdare",
    "code": "ABA",
    "lat": 51.71506,
    "lon": -3.4431
  }
]
```

Я хочу найти элемент с `code: ABA` пишу: `locations.map((key) => key.code).indexOf('ABA') > -1`. Выдает `true`, пока все ок.
После того как нашел этот `code` в данных мне нужно вывести `name` этого `code` (Должно вывести `Aberdare`). Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используя `indexOf()`.

```
var found = locations.find((loc) => {
    return loc.code === "ABA";
});

var res = found ? found.name : undefined;
```

Ответ (`name`) будет содержаться в переменной `res`. Если элемента с кодом `"ABA"` вообще не было найдено, то в `res` будет `undefined`. `undefined` также будет в том случае, если элемент по коду `"ABA"` найден, но у него нет поля `name`.

Рабочий пример:

```js
var locations = [
  {
    "name": "Alexandra Palace",
    "code": "AAP",
    "lat": 51.59793,
    "lon": -0.12023
  },
  {
    "name": "Achanalt",
    "code": "AAT",
    "lat": 57.60958,
    "lon": -4.91386
  },
  {
    "name": "Aberdare",
    "code": "ABA",
    "lat": 51.71506,
    "lon": -3.4431
  }
]

var found = locations.find((loc) => {
    return loc.code === "ABA";
});

var res = found ? found.name : undefined;
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

После применения map к массиву в выходном массиве у вас остаются только значения полей code

```js
const locations = [
  {
    "name": "Alexandra Palace",
    "code": "AAP",
    "lat": 51.59793,
    "lon": -0.12023
  },
  {
    "name": "Achanalt",
    "code": "AAT",
    "lat": 57.60958,
    "lon": -4.91386
  },
  {
    "name": "Aberdare",
    "code": "ABA",
    "lat": 51.71506,
    "lon": -3.4431
  }
];

const m = locations.map((key) => key.code);

console.log(m);
```

можно заменить map например на filter, в котором функция выполняется так же для каждого элемента массива, возвращая результат логической операции. filter создает новый массив и помещает в него все элементы массива источника для которого функция вернула true:

```js
const locations = [
  {
    "name": "Alexandra Palace",
    "code": "AAP",
    "lat": 51.59793,
    "lon": -0.12023
  },
  {
    "name": "Achanalt",
    "code": "AAT",
    "lat": 57.60958,
    "lon": -4.91386
  },
  {
    "name": "Aberdare",
    "code": "ABA",
    "lat": 51.71506,
    "lon": -3.4431
  }
];

const res = locations.filter(v => {
  return v.code === "ABA";
})[0];

console.log(res.code);
```

Comment: Второй вариант ближе к правде, но автору необходимо получить именно значение поля `name` у найденного объекта.

Comment: А использование `filter()[0]` равнозначно использованию `find()`. Хотя результат будет одинаков, но метод `find()` выполнится быстрее и потратит меньше ресурсов.

Comment: Ну да. Много решений хороших и разных. Кому-то потом поможет с проблемой **Поиск по данным и вывод результата**, когда потребуется получать не один результат, а несколько.

Comment: Именно поэтому и не минусовал. Про `find` написал на всякий случай, может вы сами не знали о нем, а так - вдруг пригодится.

Зато вот первый мой комментарий все еще в силе.

Comment: res.name вместо res.code использовать не сложно